# Tkinter StringVar() only accepts the most recent input

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, label

I'm trying to make a small application that displays words from a list one-by-one. Below is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.title('Serial Position Effect')

myArray = ['book','chair','door']
def cycle(myArray, k):
    t.set(myArray[k])

t = StringVar()

w = Label(master, height=3, width=15, font=('Helvetica', 118), textvariable = t)


for n in range(0,3):
    cycle(myArray, n)

w.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

I was expecting the label to show book, chair, and door, but it only showed door on the window. I tried to modify the for loop like:

```
for n in range(0,3):
    for x in range(0,10000):
        cycle(myArray, n)
```

Because I thought the problem was that the program was cycling through the words too quickly. But with this modified code, the application, again, only showed door after a short delay. (The delay was probably because it was counting up to 10000.)

Finally I approached this a little differently - a little less efficient but I thought by coding it like this I would be able to identify the problem in my original code:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.title('Serial Position Effect')

#myArray = ['book','chair','door']
#def cycle(myArray, k):
#    t.set(myArray[k])

t = StringVar()

w = Label(master, height=3, width=15, font=('Helvetica', 118), textvariable = t)


for n in range(0,10000)
    t.set('book')

for n in range(0,10000)
    t.set('chair')

for n in range(0,10000)
    t.set('door')

w.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

Again, the window only displayed door.

I'm new to GUI programming with Python and Tkinter. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this issue.

Thanks (=

Answer (score 3):

The window won't even show up until you call `mainloop`, so calling `set` thousands of times won't have any visible effect, except for the very last call. You should use [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) to register callback functions that change the label some seconds in the future.

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.title('Serial Position Effect')

myArray = ['book','chair','door']
def cycle(myArray, k):
    t.set(myArray[k])

t = StringVar()

w = Label(master, height=3, width=15, font=('Helvetica', 118), textvariable = t)

w.pack()
cycle(myArray,0)
master.after(1000, lambda: cycle(myArray, 1))
master.after(2000, lambda: cycle(myArray, 2))
master.mainloop()
```

---

You can also have the after-registered function call `after` itself, if you want the words to cycle forever.

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.title('Serial Position Effect')

myArray = ['book','chair','door']
cur_idx = -1
def cycle():
    global cur_idx
    cur_idx = (cur_idx + 1) % len(myArray)
    t.set(myArray[cur_idx])
    master.after(1000, cycle)

t = StringVar()

w = Label(master, height=3, width=15, font=('Helvetica', 118), textvariable = t)

w.pack()
cycle()
master.mainloop()
```